# i want to create a reference id to every order created

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, shipping-label

I want to create a **reference id** for every **order generated** on my portal and show the same **reference id** on my **shipping slip**, I am using below code

```
$attribute  = array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'backend_type'  => 'text',
        'frontend_input' => 'text',
        'is_user_defined' => true,
        'label'         => 'reference',
        'visible'       => true,
        'required'      => false,
        'user_defined'  => false,   
        'searchable'    => false,
        'filterable'    => false,
        'comparable'    => false,
        'default'       => ''
);
$installer->addAttribute('order', 'custom_reference', $attribute);
```

I will be thankful.

Answer (score 0):

The **Order** entity is not EAV in Magento. So that code wouldn't work. You'd probably need to do something like this

```
$installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
    $installer->getTable('sales_order'),
    'custom_reference',
    [
        'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
        'size' => 255,
        'nullable' => true,
        'comment' => 'custom reference'
    ]
);
```

This would add a new column to the `sales_order` table